# Is it possible to compare 3D images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to compare two 3D images?
If possible what are the possible solutions(i mean methods)?

And the purpose i want to compare two 3D images it to identify an object in that source image.
even i have one more question, at present i have been comparing converting 3d images into 2d, but i was barely used to match them by correlating.

How i can detect the object in an image(ROI)?
How to form border lines of the object if detected?
How to remove the other data in the image except leaving the object?

Comment: What do you mean with *compare*? Similarity? Subject to what? And what are 3D images? A color image plus depth, or a 4D light field?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, compare in the sense is the source image objects match with the input image. like pattern matching sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just asked about all possible questions in 3D image processing. You will not get a neat answer. Please divide, and then conquer. Please find below a few keyword to put on on track!

Is it possible to compare two 3D images? 
-> image similarity metrics, such as Mean Squares, Normalized Correlation, Pattern Intensity, Mutual Information
-> you can only do it if your images are *registered*. Check rigid registration or non-rigid registration.

Identify an object in that source image.
-> that is the topic of segmentation (in 3D), or computer vision (in 2D)

How i can detect the object in an image(ROI)?
How to form border lines of the object if detected?
-> that is the topic of Edge detection, see Canny Edge for example.

How to remove the other data in the image except leaving the object?
-> trivial, you just subtract once you've it.

Lots of resources in Medical Imaging. See what ITK can do. Some open source software include 3DSlicer, 3DSeg, ...