# How to statistically test the accuracy of 3D models?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, statistics, modeling

I have built a 3D model from a 2D image. I want to know how much accurate my model is **using some statistical test**. I think there are many available methods to do this like correlation and mean squares as mentioned in this question, [Is it possible to compare 3D images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261138/is-it-possible-to-compare-3d-images).

I couldn't find a clear description of the available tests in other sites. I've found an implementation which compares 2D images using square means here, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81048-mse-mean-square-error. I'm not sure if this can be used to calculate the model accuracy. Also, I didn't find an explanation of how the tests work, i.e. what parameters are compared (color, intensity, etc.) ?

**EDIT:** For more clarity, the 3D model represents every pixel in the 2D image as a voxel which has a color associated with it. The purpose of this model is to reconstruct the different color regions found in the 2D image into the 3D representation. So, the number of pixels that has some color (they represent a region) is calculated from the 2D image. A similar number of voxels will be constructed in the 3D model and given the same color. What matters in this modeling problem is the following,

1- size of the regions (must be almost similar in the 2D image and the model).

2-Connectivity level of a region in the 2D image and its corresponding region constructed in the 3D image must be similar. By connectivity I mean to check if the region components are scattered through the image or they are connected forming one large connected region instead of many small scattered regions of the same color.

**EDIT2: I think color correlogram is suitable**. I have found a code that implements it, but it is not clear to me. Here is the code,

```
% Soumyabrata Dev
% E-mail: soumyabr001@e.ntu.edu.sg
% http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home2012/soumyabr001/
I= imread ('img.jpg');
correlogram_vector=[];
[Y,X]=size(rgb2gray(I));

% quantize image into 64 colors = 4x4x4, in RGB space
[img_no_dither, ~] = rgb2ind(I, 64, 'nodither');
% figure, imshow(img_no_dither, map);
%rgb = ind2rgb(img_no_dither, map); % rgb = double(rgb)
distance_vector= [1 3]; 
[~,d]=size(distance_vector);
count_matrix=zeros(64,d);   total_matrix=zeros(64,d);
prob_dist=cell(1,d);

for serial_no=1:1:d
    for x=1:X
        for y=1:Y
            color=img_no_dither(y,x);

            % At the given distance 
            [positive_count,total_count]=get_n(distance_vector(serial_no),x,y,color,img_no_dither,X,Y);
            count_matrix(color+1,serial_no)=count_matrix(color+1,serial_no)+positive_count;
            total_matrix(color+1,serial_no)=total_matrix(color+1,serial_no)+total_count;       
        end
    end

    prob_dist{serial_no}=count_matrix(:,serial_no)./(1+total_matrix(:,serial_no));

end

for serial_no=1:d
    correlogram_vector=cat(1,correlogram_vector,prob_dist{serial_no});
end

end
```

This is the method get_n,

```
function [positive_count,total_count]=get_n(n,x,y,color,img_no_dither,X,Y)
% This function is useful to get the validity map of the neighborhood case.
% It can handle any number of neighborhood distances.

% Input
% n=The order of the neighborhood
% x & y= x y co-ordinates of the given pixel
% color= particular quantized color
% img_no_dither= The color quantized image matrix
% X & Y= The original dimensions of the input image

% Output
% positive_count= The number of occurences which have the same color
% total_count= The total number of valid cases for this particular instant


    valid_vector8n=zeros(1,8*n); % This is because of the propoerty of inf-norm. Each distance has 8 times the order
    positive_count=0;   total_count=0;

    nbrs_x=zeros(1,8*n);    nbrs_y=zeros(1,8*n);

    % The counting of the pixels is done in the following manner: From the
    % given pixel, go left-->up-->right-->down-->left-->up
    % Y co-ordinates of nbrs
    nbrs_y(1)=y;
    d=1;
    for k=2:1+n
       nbrs_y(k)=y-d;
       d=d+1;
    end

    nbrs_y(1+n:1:3*n+1)=y-n;

    d=0;
    for k=3*n+1:5*n+1
       nbrs_y(k)=y-n+d;
       d=d+1;
    end

    nbrs_y(5*n+1:1:7*n+1)=y+n;

    d=0;
    for k=7*n+1:1:7*n+1+(n-1)
       nbrs_y(k)=y+n-d;
       d=d+1;
    end

    % X co-ordinates of nbrs
    nbrs_x(1)=x-n;

    nbrs_x(2:1:1+n)=x-n;

    d=0;
    for k=1+n:1:3*n+1
        nbrs_x(k)=x-n+d;
        d=d+1;
    end

    nbrs_x(3*n+1:5*n+1)=x+n;

    d=0;
    for k=5*n+1:7*n+1
        nbrs_x(k)=x+n-d;
        d=d+1;
    end

    nbrs_x(7*n+1:7*n+1+(n-1))=x-n;

    % Assigning the validity of the neighborhood
    for i=1:8*n

        if nbrs_x(i)>0 && nbrs_x(i)<=X && nbrs_y(i)>0 && nbrs_y(i)<=Y
            valid_vector8n(i)=1;

        else
            valid_vector8n(i)=0;

        end

    end


    % Couting the number of common colors in the valid areas of the
    % neighborhood.
    for j=1:8*n
       if valid_vector8n(j)==1
          data= img_no_dither(nbrs_y(j),nbrs_x(j));
          if (data==color)
              positive_count=positive_count+1;
          end
          total_count=total_count+1;
       end
    end

end
```

Can anyone please clarify how this code works?

The code above is for **autocorrelogram** not **correlogram**. I've read that the first is better, but it can only calculate the spatial probability using pixels of the same colors (can't be applied on pairs of pixels which have different colors). Is this right?

Thank You.

Comment: I suggest rather than asking for a detailed listing with multiple answers, you try to focus the question on the purpose of your model (is it for (re-)visualisation artwork, surveying, robotic navigation?), and give the nature of your ground truth data. A little matlab code to help explain that could keep things on-topic. For an accuracy metric to be useful it needs to be possible to calculate it, *plus* it needs to be relevant to the original problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @NeilSlater I edited the question. Please take a look at it. Thank You.

Comment: This is unfortunately still far too broad. I suggest you look at the literature for your field to see sort of methods are commonly used and then select an appropriate metric based on that information and your knowledge about your data.

Comment: @nkjt Thanks, but I have searched a lot. I could not find a clear resource. Can you please explain any commonly used method for testing 3D model?

Comment: It seems you want to compare some metrics reconstructed from the 3d model with those directly extracted from the underlying 2d image. So far so good. However, I don't see any way to make a statistical test here, since you have only one instance. For any kind of test you need a sample, e.g. a sample of images and corresponding 3d models. Also, what would be the null hypothesis to be tested?

Comment: @A.Donda, thanks a lot for your comment. I used one 2D image only to build the model. But I have other two 2D images which are cuts from different axis (slices). Can these be used to evaluate the model (I built only one model)? If I understand correctly, null hypothesis is something we try to reject in favor for the alternative one. So, I think null hypothesis is "the model does not accurately represent the structure of the original 2D image". I want to disprove that. Maybe we can use some image processing technique to disprove it. Can you please help me? What test can I use? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see this happening with three different cuts either. Normally different sample values need to be statistically independent. You can try your luck on stats.SE (flag your question and ask a moderator to move it there), but I'm not optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Classical workflow:

1. find matching features in both models,
2. calculate the distance,
3. ??????,
4. PROFIT!!

Comment: thank you, I've already built my own algorithm which has some similar aspects to those you have mentioned. Thanks for providing this useful answer.